# Static int main issue

Tags: c#, console-application, program-entry-point

This is a **Console Program**

Scenario:

I have a many function in my c# code and is set to be Public and Private. And I have `static int Main(string args[])` of course. In `int Main` i calling some function Public and Private and thats interupting the function when i debug that. It says if main was *static* so all function must be *static*, yet my code in function Public and Private must be have "that" function. If i change `static int Main` with my `public int main`, debug cant be done because `int Main` must be static.

First im saying i really sorry for giving a non-understable question

If that's so confusing understanding my scenario, see my Example Code Here

```
namespace Example
{
   class Program
   {
      public class ClassInPublic
      {
          public int Num;
          public string Sentence;
      }

      ClassInPublic DeclaringInstance = new ClassInPublic();

      private void Foo()
      {
          DeclaringInstance.Num = 35;
          DeclaringInstance.Sentence = "Hello World";
          Console.Write("This Private Function! And Assign Variable Value From ClassInPublic Variable");
      }

      private void Foo2()
      {
          Console.Write("This Single Foo didnt have any Instance Class");
      }

      static int Main(string args[])
      {
          Foo();
      }
   }
}
```

That's my case

And with help from others i already build this

```
namespace Example
{
   class Program
   {
      public static class ClassInPublic
      {
          public int Num;
          public string Sentence;
      }

      ClassInPublic DeclaringInstance = new ClassInPublic();

      private static void Foo()
      {
          DeclaringInstance.Num = 35;
          DeclaringInstance.Sentence = "Hello World";
          Console.Write("This Private Function! And Assign Variable Value From ClassInPublic Variable");
      }

      private static void Foo2()
      {
          Console.Write("This Single Foo didnt have any Instance Class");
      }

      public static int Main(string args[])
      {
          Foo();
      }
   }
}
```

Error sign is lower right now, the rest is the ClassInPublic

It says i cannot declare

```
cannot declare instance members in static class
```

May someone assist me to overcome this?

Comment: You need to understand what `static` means.  See the documentation.

Comment: Your question is very unclear. Please show some actual code and highlight where the error is reported so we can understand the issue.

Comment: Well it is hard for me to explain the solution, as it is more of a classroom question. But if I may suggest you to make a habit to never write functions where you write static main. Just create a class and define all functionality there and just call that class object in main. just for sake of good habit.

Comment: How do you even have `private` or `public` outside the scope of a class?  main can't refer to these functions - it can create an instance of your class, and call the public functions on it.

Comment: See: [Static and instance methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645766(v=vs.71).aspx)

Comment: sorry, i didnt read a single documentation about static means, i just practicing over.

Comment: @p.s.w.g I already fixed it, please see updated my question

Comment: @SumitGupta I already fixed my question, see it if you want sir

Comment: @ScottMermelstein hm, to be honest the class thing is confusing for me. Oh yeah i already fixed my question, see it

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace Example
{
    class Program
    {

        public void foo()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("This is foo in Class Program");
        }

        static void fooStatic()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("This is Static foo");
        }


        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Program fooInstance = new Program();

            fooStatic();
            fooInstance.foo();

        }
    }
}
```

Here is a small example. Static functions are one per class. When you make public or private function they exist for each instance.

Edit:

Here is what I think you are trying to do:

```
namespace Example
{
   class Program
   {
      public class ClassInPublic
      {
          static public int Num;
          static public string Sentence;
      }

      ClassInPublic DeclaringInstance = new ClassInPublic();

      private static void Foo()
      {
          ClassInPublic.Num = 35;
          ClassInPublic.Sentence = "Hello World";
          Console.WriteLine("This Private Function! And Assign Variable Value From ClassInPublic Variable");
      }

      private static void Foo2()
      {
          Console.Write("This Single Foo didnt have any Instance Class\n");
      }

      public static int Main(string[] args)
      {
          Foo();
          return 0;
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: static functions can have accessibility modifiers, just as instance methods can choose to omit them (and use the default).

Comment: Don't need the Console.ReadKey()